# Jquery form validation - enforcing alphanumeric

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, alphanumeric

Does anyone know why this validation is not working, I am trying to enforce alphanumeric input of 8-12 chars but nothing is happening, I have linked to the external jquery form validation library as you can see:

```
<form id="userTest">    
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>Password</td><td><input type="password" id="pwd"></input></td>
   </tr>
 </table>
</form>
```

The Jquery:

```
$(function(){
    $("form#userTest").validate({
         rules:{
              pwd:{
                   alphanumeric: true,
                   minlength: 8,
                   maxlength: 12      
              }
         }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zCjav/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing the [additional-methods.js](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js) file where the alpha-numeric rule is added, also you might want to add the required validation

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("form#userTest").validate({
        rules:{
            pwd:{
                required: true,
                alphanumeric: true,
                minlength: 8,
                maxlength: 12     
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aCnd8/)

Comment: thanks what a stupid error on my part. I can't believe  that I used to have to write my own validation code in PHP. This is so much easier.

Comment: Alan, you'll still want to do validation in PHP - Javascript is easily disabled in the user's browser!